# Paging, sorting and filtering with angularJs, small issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-filters

I have this annoying issue that when putting paging, and try to do sorting or filtering it is difficult to make work altogether, there are so many examples on the internet, I am writing cause I am not able to resolve the last two issues. I apologize for this very common question.

The two issues I have are:

- I have the array of 11 elements and the paging configured to hold 5 rows, means I am expecting to have 3 pages and I have only 2.
- and if I type something in the text box of the filter, getting let say 1 or 2 rows, if eventually, I click in one header column for sorting, it removes the filter.

My impression is that there is an easy way to do all these without reinventing the wheel?

this is my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 
'ui.bootstrap']);

 app.controller('controller', function($scope, $filter) {

 //Variable initialization
 //$scope.filteredArray = [];
 $scope.currentPage = 0;
 $scope.numPerPage = 5;
 $scope.maxSize = 8;
 $scope.arrayFilter = '';

 $scope.sortType = ''; // set the default sort type
 $scope.sortReverse = true; // set the default sort order

 //Creates the items
 $scope.arrayList = [{
  Id: 1,
  Name: 'Marcos'
 }, {
  Id: 2,
  Name: 'Marcelo'
 }, {
  Id: 3,
  Name: 'Ben'
 }, {
  Id: 4,
  Name: 'Stuart'
 }, {
  Id: 5,
  Name: 'Jhon'
 }, {
  Id: 6,
  Name: 'Paul'
 }, {
  Id: 7,
  Name: 'Leticia'
 }, {
  Id: 8,
  Name: 'Ramon'
 }, {
  Id: 9,
  Name: 'Jose'
 }, {
  Id: 10,
  Name: 'Ronaldo'
 }, {
  Id: 11,
  Name: 'Test'
 }];

 //$scope.filteredArray = $scope.arrayList.slice(0, 5);
 $scope.ArrayLength = $scope.arrayList.length;
 $scope.filteredArray = $scope.arrayList.slice(0, $scope.numPerPage);

 $scope.onPageChange = function() {
 //$scope.filterFunction();
 $scope.begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.numPerPage);
 $scope.end = $scope.begin + $scope.numPerPage;
 $scope.filteredArray = $scope.arrayList.slice($scope.begin, $scope.end);
 }

 $scope.sort = function(field) {
   $scope.sortType = field;
   $scope.sortReverse = !$scope.sortReverse;
   var sorted = $filter('orderBy')($scope.arrayList, field, 
    $scope.sortReverse);
   $scope.arrayList = sorted;
   $scope.filteredArray = sorted.slice(0, 5);
 }

 $scope.filterFunction = function() {

 var filtered = $filter('filter')($scope.arrayList, $scope.arrayFilter);

 // $scope.arrayList = filtered;
 $scope.ArrayLength = filtered.length;

 //perform the paging
 $scope.filteredArray = filtered.slice(0, 5);
 };

});
```

This is my plunker.
https://plnkr.co/edit/mQUSVxj3PWtZWL0tYD2z?p=preview

Thanks!

Comment: Think you need `items-per-page` in the directive - I also thought to mention that your code is doing lots of filtering that angular can do for you quite easily. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter. Check out the `tr ng-repeat` using `orderBy` and `filter` in this plunk https://embed.plnkr.co/YgzkybXPzIUtyJa92pJf/ there's no need to clutter the controller with filtering methods

Comment: Thanks, your paging does not work.

Comment: I liked your logic, if this could work, it will be amazing, mainly this part looks great: ng-repeat="item in filteredArray = (arrayList | orderBy:orderBy:reverse | filter:filters)"   but the paging is not working!

Comment: This line is an improvement of what you suggested but, the last thing is that it is not updated the number of pages when you do a filter: <tr ng-repeat="item in filteredArray = (arrayList.slice(begin, end) | orderBy:orderBy:reverse | filter:filters)">   , here is the plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/rYVeMt5WdG3T7z4LHHM3?p=preview

Comment: Try this out - it's pretty close and allows for searching the entire arrayList, not just items for the page you're on. Note the use of a `memo` object in the js, the `limitTo:5` in the `ng-repeat` and the `total-items` logic in the uib-pagination directive https://plnkr.co/edit/KYCp0PgUjYnESH0ceTIl?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for putting a lot of effort on this. Unfortunately is not working fully. The sorting is better now, but it is happening for the current page. If you play a bit clicking many times in the same sorting column the numbers changes and by clicking the paging the numbers does not match :(. In my original questions, that was the issue, not being able to make work altogether: paging, sorting and filtering, it looks easy but I was not able to complete the code.

Answer (score 0):

These two changes should fix your problem:

In your template you need to use the `items-per-page` directive for `uib-pagination`:

```
 <ul uib-pagination items-per-page="5" direction-links="false" boundary-links="true" total-items="ArrayLength" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" ng-change="onPageChange()">
```

In your `$scope.sort()` function, you need to slice your array with the correct length of the filtered array:

```
$scope.filteredArray = sorted.slice(0, $scope.arrayList.length);
```

Comment: As a sub-note, I personally like to use [angular-tablesort](http://mattiash.github.io/angular-tablesort/) to handle all the sorting and let bootstrap handle the pagination because I too do not enjoy re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @MarcosF8, sorry should be `$scope.arrayList.length`

Comment: Thanks for that again. it still does not work cause: if the $scope.arrayList.length is 11, and you click a header column, it is going to do a slice between 0 and 11 and it gives a page of 11 elements and not one of 5 elements